# Cannot find include file <mqueue.h> on OS X?

Tags: c++, osx-lion

I am unable to use mqueue.h in mac. When I try to include this header file in my C++ program it says Cannot find include file . Is there a way to use this in mac ? Or are there any universal alternatives to this.

I want to use the O_NOBLOCK flag which is present in mqueue.h ?

I found out that the IPC message queues have the following restrictions which may be useful before making a decision to use them.

```
Max Number of Msg Queue Identifiers = 16
Max Size of Messages = 8192 (Bytes)
Default Max Size of a Message Queue = 16384
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mqueue.h` is for POSIX messaging queues, and is not available on OS X.
`O_NONBLOCK` has nothing to do with that, and is defined in `fcntl.h`.

`#include <sys/fcntl.h>`

should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recall what mqueue.h is, but it's not needed for O_NONBLOCK.  You want `<fcntl.h>`.

Comment: I was actually trying to use IPC using message queues and when I tried to include this header file in Netbeans 7.0.1 in Mac OS X 10.7 Lion it gave me an error stating cannot find include.