# <mqueue.h> and mqd_t on OS X

Tags: xcode, macos, posix

I'm trying to compile a simulation of FreeRTOS on OS X. The simulation code is written for UNIX (POSIX) so I thought that I can comile it on OS X, too.

But I have difficulties with some POSIX threading stuff. XCode can't find the header  and thus the type mqd_t is missing.

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to install some additional libraries? I thoght that OS X is POSIX compatible.

Thx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot find include file <mqueue.h> on OS X?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079403/cannot-find-include-file-mqueue-h-on-os-x)

Comment: As suggested on [Cannot find include file <mqueue.h> on OS X?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079403/cannot-find-include-file-mqueue-h-on-os-x) I tried to include `#include <sys/fcntl.h>`. Then the compiler doesn't complain about not finding the include file. But it still complains about not knowing the type `mqd_t`.

Comment: That's because `mqd_t` is defined in `mqueue.h` and that doesn't exist.  OSX doesn't support POSIX message queues.

Comment: Ok thanks. I thoght that OS X is POSIX compatible...

Comment: Sure, but the level of compliance isn't 100%.

Comment: Ok thanks. Is there an OS X alternative to `mpd_t`? Sorry I'm not familiar with POSIX Threads. So any directions? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.  Google will have something for you, I'm sure.

Comment: I'ts not so easy to find something. I tried before posting to SO. But I will dig deeper... Thanks anyway!